# Before Action Authenticate with Devise and STI not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use `before_action :authenticate_admin!` to determine if the current user is an admin or not. I am using devise with single table inheritance (STI).

Here is my User model;

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def admin?
    false
  end
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable
end
```

And my Admin model;

```
class Users::Admin < User
  def devise_scope
    :admin
  end

  def admin?
    true
  end
end
```

Just to test out devise, I have this in my routes file;

```
authenticated :user, ->(u) { u.admin? } do
  resources :teams
end
```

And indeed, if I am signed in as a different User type (so *not* Admin), I can't get to that resource.

But this fails to work;

```
class Teams < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  def index

  end
end
```

I get the error;

> undefined method `authenticate_admin!'

Quite new to Rails so I don't understand how to resolve this.

**UPDATE**

I had to put this in the routes file;

```
devise_for :admins, class_name: 'Users::Admin'
```

Previously I only had;

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions'}
```

Comment: Do the other devise methods work? 'current_admin', 'admin_signed_in?' ? etc

Comment: don't worry I solved it. See update.